# Troubleshooting Packaging Error of General function failure?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, map-package, general-function-failure

Have some problems with sharing my map on ArcGIS Online:

As a student, I am now working with my master thesis and I use ArcGIS Online as a workflow based sharing network. I work locally on my computer and share my work with my supervisor via ArcGIS Online. My supervisor downloads the .mpk file and gives me feedback on my work.

This has worked fine until now. Today I was going to send my updated work and I get the error message:

> Error Packaging - General function failure.

I do exactly the same as before, as follows: log in with my ArcGIS Online account (in arcmap), click File --> Share As, Map Package, overwrite my previous file and hit Share. The analyze process reports no problems. After a while I get the message

> Packaging Error - General function failure.

What to do?

I'm running ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 for Desktop.

Comment: Any answer to this question? I'm having the same issue still with 10.1

Comment: if there are errors try adding summary, tags, and map description under Item description.

Answer (score 2):

I used the `Check Geometry` function to see if there was any geometry problems in my feature classes. Then, I used the `Repair Geometry` tool to fix the problems. When I tried to share my map as a map package after completing this steps I was able to upload it to ArcGIS online.

Running ArcMap 10.3

Answer (score 1):

please check your layer's name if they consist of "." remove please, this also causes general function failure while creating mpk file.
use "_" where space is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change folder to save your file?
I had the same error, I found out that I had changed the folder and was not anymore in a registered one.
I changed it back to the "Home" and it worked.